# jQuery won't find element with ID Selector, but will find it with ID alone

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET app and using jQuery. I have a `<div>` element with the `id='slider'`. When trying to access the element using `$('#slider')`, it returns `null`, but when trying to access it without the selector, ie. `$('slider')` the element is returned.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Hmm, thats... *unlikely*. Could you show your code -- HTML and Javascript?

Comment: We need some code to see. Like @lonesomeday said, Jquery wouldn't return an element with that selector, unless your code had a `<slider></slider>` element on the page, which isn't an HTML element.

Comment: *Are* you using jQuery and not, for example, Prototype.JS? Because the latter is prototype notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the selector doesn't match, then jQuery doesn't return `null`. So that's two counts of "Acting unlike jQuery" which suggests that the answer is: `$` is not jQuery in your page.

Something else is redefining it. Possibly mootools or prototype.js (I'm not sure what either return if there is no matching element, but I'm pretty sure that both have a `$` function that takes an id and not a CSS selector as the argument).

Comment: OK, that's explains a lot. Looks like I'm having a link to prototype AND jquery on the same page, and I really need them both. 
How can I use both of them in the same page?

Comment: try writing `$ = jquery` before you use the $

Comment: Use jQuery's [non-conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and refer to it as `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

as specified above prototype has caused the problem.

Solution: you have to use jquery noconflict. When you will use this any jquery code will preserve $ variable before it starts to execute and after execution of the jquery code this will restore the value of $.

link: [api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)